# If condition for functions

Tags: jquery

So, I have the following js file which checks for few functions:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    RebindClickModal_show();
    RebindClickModal_contact();     
});
```

However if a page does not have these functions, then I get reference error.

So, I want to add a `if` condition to check to see if these functions exists first.

What would be the best way doing it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try using `isFunction` like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    if ( $.isFunction($.fn.RebindClickModal_show) ) {
         RebindClickModal_show();
    }


    if ( $.isFunction($.fn.RebindClickModal_contact) ) {
        RebindClickModal_contact();  
    }

});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check then wheather function exist using

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    if(RebindClickModal_show && typeof RebindClickModal_show === typeof Function) {
        RebindClickModal_show();
    }

    if(RebindClickModal_contact && typeof RebindClickModal_contact === typeof Function) {
        RebindClickModal_contact();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you! Appreciate it! :)

Answer (score 1):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    ($.isFunction(window.RebindClickModal_show))?( RebindClickModal_show() ):( "" );
    ($.isFunction(window.RebindClickModal_contact))?( RebindClickModal_contact() ):( "" );
});

function RebindClickModal_show(){
    console.log("Show - Hello World!");
}
function RebindClickModal_contact(){
    console.log("Contact - Hello World!");
}
```